# Submitting a new records via form to my django database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create new objects in my database and if all goes well send the user to a table where all records are being posted, but for some reason the form is seems to be submitting successfully but no new records are being added to my database.

Here are my codes:
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
    class clearance(models.Model):
        vessel_imo = models.ForeignKey(vessel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        vessel_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,)
        email = models.EmailField(default='john@doe.com')
        location = models.CharField(default='PACCT',max_length=30,choices=LIST_OF_PORTS)
        clearance_file1 = models.FileField()
        status = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CLEARANCE_STATUS,default='PENDING')
        requestdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,auto_created=True,editable=False)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.vessel_name
        
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-id']
```

form.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . models import clearance, vessel

class ClearanceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = clearance
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
def new(request):
    form = ClearanceForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
            
    return render(request,'new.html',{'form':form})
```

new.html:

```
{% extends 'dashboard.html' %}

{% block title %}
<h2> REQUEST FOR CLEARANCE</h2>
{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<form action="pendings.html" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


{% endblock content %}
```

What I am trying to get is the user to add a new records in the database and be sent to the dashboard.html where he can see all records including the just added.

Comment: I'd look to that `action="pendings.html"` as a potential issue. Typically you'd have a `{% url "yourapp:yourmethod" %}` there. Do you have something in your `urls.py` patterns that will respond to 'pendings.html'?

Comment: I guess... honestly I am not getting it very well, here is my code:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . views import loginaction, pendings, new, registration

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',loginaction),
    path('dashboard.html',loginaction),
    path('pendings.html',pendings),
    path('new.html',new),
    path('registration.html',registration),
]